# jQuery UI Sortable - Strange behaviour - items falling from the top of window on move

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm experiencing some very strange behaviour with jQuery UI sortable.

I'm using jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery UI 1.10.3.

In FF the first time you move an item, it works fine but after you have moved it once, when you move it again, it jumps and falls from the top of the window to under your cursor rather than just peeling away from it's position.

In Chrome, this happens irrespective of if you have moved it previously.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="trackListings" id="trackListings">
    <li class="header">
        <div class="number">#</div>
        <div class="title">Title</div>
        <div class="length">Length</div>
        <div class="plays">Plays</div>
        <div class="adds">Adds</div>
        <div class="toggle"></div>
    </li>
    <li id="369">
        <div class="number">1</div>
        <div class="title">Test track</div>
        <div class="length">1:25</div>
        <div class="plays">0</div>
        <div class="adds">0</div>
        <div class="toggle"><span>&gt;</span></div>
        <div class="actions">Purchase Link: <input placeholder="e.g iTunes, Amazon etc" value="" type="text"></div>
    </li>

    <li id="370">
        <div class="number">2</div>
        <div class="title">Test track 2</div>
        <div class="length">1:29</div>
        <div class="plays">0</div>
        <div class="adds">0</div>
        <div class="toggle"><span>&gt;</span></div>
        <div class="actions">Purchase Link: <input placeholder="e.g iTunes, Amazon etc" value="" type="text"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Appropriate CSS:

```
.trackListings{
    padding:0;

}
.trackListings li{
    line-height: 50px;
    display: inline;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #afb2b4;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #000;
    transition:.25s linear all;
}

.trackListings li:after{
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    content: " ";
}
.trackListings li div{
    float: left;
}
.trackListings li div.number{
    text-align: center;
    width: 45px;
}

.trackListings li div.title{
    width: 465px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.trackListings li div.length{
    width: 110px;
}

.trackListings li div.plays{
    width: 100px;
}

.trackListings li div.adds{
    width: 210px;
}

.trackListings li div.toggle span{
    font-size: 30px; 
    display: block;
}

.trackListings li.active div.toggle span{
    color: #e35b29;
}
.trackListings li div.actions{
    display: none;
}
```

And am initialising it like so:

```
$('#trackListings').sortable({
                items: 'li:not(.header)'
            });
```

I've tried removing the containing divs and setting a fixed height on the lis. Also have tried wrapping in a relatively positioned div but this caused it to happen every time in FF too.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle if this is not yet resolved

Answer (score 1):

Solved it enabling forceFallback in SortableJS options: https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable#options

```
options = { forceFallback: true, }
```

I'm using it with Vue 3, Vuetify and sortablejs-vue3: https://github.com/MaxLeiter/sortablejs-vue3

Comment: this just helped me with sortablejs in a rails app. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I came across something similar to this a while ago, and documented here: http://blog.ricky-stevens.com/jquery-sortable-offset-bug/ and it has since been discussed here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/sortable-offset-when-element-is-dragged-and-page-scrolled-down-ff

It might be related. This affects jQuery Sortable if you have to scroll on the page. Try adjusting the scroll-y properties on the body tag.

Comment: Unfortunately that was a different issue. I have noticed however that when an item has moved to a new position it has position: relative; left: 0px; top:0px; when I remove this in firebug, I'm able to redrag it from it's current position....

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the behaviour in FF by using the `helper:"clone"` option of sortable. It goes some way to fixing in chrome but still not perfect

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a incredibly old, but I came across this issue today. The fix is to remove:

```
position: relative;
```

from the css on the list item. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old one, but for me it fixed it by not using "revert: true".